# Show form field based on item list

Tags: laravel-4

Is it possible to display an input form field based on the value of a select menu? Or is this something I'd have to do in javascript/jquery?

My list is pulled from the database if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this happen during the form filling, yes you probably will need to use Ajax (via vanilla Javascript or jQuery), if you need to query your database as options are selected, or just CSS: http://www.coderanch.com/t/594720/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Show-Hide-text-box-select, if you populated via database but don't need to check it again for changes.